# Comparing two times without date in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

Let's assume I have two times with no date as shown below.

```
>>> time_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("05:30", "%H:%M")
>>> time_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("05:00", "%H:%M")
```

To compare these two, I can simply do this:

```
>>> time_1<= time_2
False
```

Now, for this example when I know 03:30 happens before "23:30", I get `False` as well.

```
>>> time_1=datetime.datetime.strptime("23:30", "%H:%M")
>>> time_2=datetime.datetime.strptime("03:30", "%H:%M")
>>> time_1<= time_2
False
```

I am trying to know if there is any way to handle this situations?

Comment: ...but `03:30` does not happen before `23:30`. Python is doing the right thing. If you compare the time with another time from _the next day_ you can add 1 day to it, e.g. `time_2 += datetime.timedelta(days=1)`.

Comment: @Selcuk I agree. I am dealing with a cyclic time where 23:30 is occurring before next day 3:30am.

Comment: Is there a cutoff date? Should 8pm also come before 3am?

Comment: @MrFuppes not sure how?

Comment: @Selcuk cut-off is 24:00

Comment: That comment doesn't make sense. 23:30 is before 24:00.

Comment: Do you want the date to be the smaller one so that the time delta between the two times is minimized?

Comment: Why not convert it into seconds and compare them then? `5:30`-> `50(60^2)+30` (or minutes since its your bottom value)

Answer (score 0):

```
if time2 < time1:
   time2 += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

assuming the second time is always the next day if it is less than the first time

Comment: Not sure how this helps. This will cause `time1 <= time2` to always return `True`, making it a tautology.

Comment: That is true. The suggested way by @Joran will cause that issue.

Comment: besides, timedelta arithmetic is not defined for the datetime.time class

Comment: @MrFuppes It's a `datetime`, not `time`.

Comment: @Selcuk adding an arbitrary date won't help solve the problem I think

Comment: @MrFuppes Blindly adding a day won't help, but it's the solution if you know when to add.

Answer (score 0):

***assuming the time strings represent a *time series*, i.e. they appear in chronological order***, one can derive datetime by adding as duration to an arbitrary date (I have to revise my comment @Selcuk ...). Something like

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

# assuming the "cyclic time" looks similar to this:
cycletimes = ["05:00", "05:30", "23:30", "03:30"]

# we can convert to timedelta;
# to_td converts HH:MM string to timedelta
to_td = lambda s: timedelta(hours=int(s.split(':')[0]), minutes=int(s.split(':')[1]))
durations = list(map(to_td, cycletimes))

# take an arbitrary date
refdate = datetime.combine(datetime.today().date(), time.min)
# what we want is datetime; we can already set the first entry
datetimes = [refdate+durations[0]]

# now we iterate over cycle times; if the next value is smaller, we add a day to refdate
for t0, t1, d in zip(cycletimes[:-1], cycletimes[1:], durations[1:]):
    if t1 < t0:
        refdate += timedelta(1)
    datetimes.append(refdate+d)


print(f"{datetimes[0]} <= {datetimes[1]} -> {datetimes[0] <= datetimes[1]}")
# 2021-08-26 05:00:00 <= 2021-08-26 05:30:00 -> True

print(f"{datetimes[2]} <= {datetimes[3]} -> {datetimes[2] <= datetimes[3]}")
# 2021-08-26 23:30:00 <= 2021-08-27 03:30:00 -> True
```

Now for example "23:30" appears *before* "03:30", not after as if you'd only compare time. Side note, pure Python is great to illustrate the logic here; in the "real world" however I'd suggest to have a look at the `pandas` library for such a task.

Comment: Thanks- Made a small change the list elements and I am getting this using the suggested methos:
cycletimes = ["05:30", "05:00", "23:30", "21:30"] 2021-08-26 05:30:00 <= 2021-08-27 05:00:00 -> True
2021-08-27 23:30:00 <= 2021-08-28 21:30:00 -> True

Comment: @armin because you did not pay attention to the constraint I stated above: "*appear in chronological order*" ;-) Your example won't work - I don't see any reasonable logic how to handle arbitrary appearance of times, I think you *must* include constraints.